# How to put these checkboxes in a session?

Tags: php, session, insert, checkbox

I have the following snippet:

```
foreach($_POST['status'] as &$status){
    mysql_real_escape_string($status);
}
```

How do I wrap this in a session like `$_SESSION['status']` or something so I can insert this into the database? This code is situated on page 2 of a 5 page form so thats why I can't just insert it using $_POST['status'].

Comment: Simply insert 0 or 1 according to the post variable in $_SESSION['status'] and on each page later on check if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'])

Comment: thanks but what do you mean insert 0 or 1 to the post variable? I am new to PHP so i don;t get that part..

Answer (score 0):

As you have a five page form you need the status variable to be inserted either in the session or in database so that you can use them till the end...

Both the things are quite easy..And there exists one third method also..

To store it in session create a session variable like $_SESSION['status'] and insert the value you have got for the status and on all subsequent pages call them as:
    if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'])

To insert into database just insert this info along with what you have got in first page, but I won't suggest that, as user may abort registration after first page..

Third method is to make them as 
    ">

By this you can get the values on next form submit place also with $_POST['status_again']..